# I am looking for the right word for a board above the door of a small store or restuarant(like in the picture)

Tags: word-choice

What should I call them? a Nameboard? a Board? a Plaque?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In general, you could refer to such a sign as a "store sign" or perhaps a "retail sign". You might also call it a "[marquee](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/marquee)"; it is different from a typical marquee but close enough that you would be understood.

The round sign on the far left looks as though it projects from the facade; in that case, it might be called a "[shingle](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shingle)".

I speak American English; other people may use different terms.

Comment: In Australian English a *marquee* is a large tent. We would find that word confusing here. "Shingle" usually refers to a medical or legal practice. Perhaps "shop sign" or just "sign".

Comment: @Peter - yes, I always consider 'shingle' to be a particularly US term & marquee would also be first thought to be a large tent in the UK too. Strictly, the store sign is a kind of marquee, but it's just not in common-enough use in that way for a Brit to recognise it. I'd call it a 'shop sign' or the 'sign above the shop [window]' or other tortuous roundabout phrase… there isn't a single-word term I can think of to unambiguously replace it.

Comment: as another Brit I'd only ever call all these things "signs". I'd understand marquee as an Americanism, but it would throw me for a loop a bit. I wouldn't understand shingle at all, and if I needed to distinguish between the different types I'd have to use a long-winded phrase like @gonefishin'again.

Comment: Now I understand, Thank you!